# How do I fix my java program not stopping running?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, system.in

I am writing a simple program as some practice for Java. It takes in integers and puts them into a two-dimensional array of R rows and C columns and then simply prints out each element of the array (just for troubleshooting). When I run the code it prints every integer like it should but the program does not stop running. I have to force stop it. Why is it not stopping on its own? I tried some basic debugging and tried to see if I accidentally had an infinite loop in the code but I couldn't find it.

In case it is important I am using IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2019.3.

Thanks

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        int T = in.nextInt(); //Takes number of test cases
        for(int i = 1; i <= T; i++){ //This is the counter for each test case
            int R = in.nextInt(); //R is # of rows
            int C = in.nextInt(); //C is # of columns
            int K = in.nextInt(); //K is the thickness allowed
            int numArray[][] = new int[R+1][C+1];

            for(int j = 0; j < R; j++){
                for(int k = 0; k < C; k++){
                    numArray[j][k] = in.nextInt();
                    System.out.println(numArray[j][k]);
                }
            }

        }
        in.close();
    }//End of main
}//End of main class
```

Edit: Just for future reference I will include the input and the output I was getting.

Input: 
3
1 4 0
3 1 3 3
2 3 0
4 4 5
7 6 6
4 5 0
2 2 4 4 20
8 3 3 3 12
6 6 3 3 3
1 6 8 6 4

Output:
3
1
3
3
4
4
5
7
6
6
2
2
4
4
20
8
3
3
3
12
6
6
3
3
3
1
6
8
6
(and here the cursor is stuck blinking not doing anything and the program doesn't quit on its own)

I solved the issue by manually typing the input instead of copying and pasting it. Not sure what caused that issue but it worked!

Comment: Please provide console output

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This little piece of code requires the user to input 3 integers (`R`, `C`  and `K`) `T`-times:

```
int T = in.nextInt(); 
for(int i = 1; i <= T; i++){
    int R = in.nextInt(); 
    int C = in.nextInt();
    int K = in.nextInt(); 
    // ...
}
```

Additionally the user has to input an integer `R*C`-times until `i <= T`:

```
for(int j = 0; j < R; j++){
    for(int k = 0; k < C; k++){
        numArray[j][k] = in.nextInt(); // << requires user-interaction each loop here >>
        System.out.println(numArray[j][k]);
    }
}
```

If you use `T`=1, `R`=1, `C`=1, `K`=1 the user has to input only 1 additional integer, as there is only 1 test-repitition and `R*C` = 1. With that your program terminates just as expected.

With bigger values of `T`, `R`, `C`, `K` the required user-interactions grow exponentially, which probably makes you think that your program should have ended but it still waits for additional user-input.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I figured out the issue. I was copying and pasting the test inputs from a web page. I tried double checking to make sure the input was valid and then inputting them by hand and it fixed it. Not 100% why but that fixes the problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -2):

your for(int i = 1; i <= T; i++) probably newer ends because you are increasing T.

You need to made some condition in loop to exit. For example
if (xx == yy) break;